# How would I put strings into my object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, netbeans

Here is what I am suppose to do in my project:

> Here is what you do: create a class named MyRecord (MyRecord.java) with the 
>       variables firstname, lastname, email, idnumber, color and balance. Use the 
>       appropriate data type for each field.

So I created that class as follows:

```
public class MyRecord {

    String firstname, lastname, email, color;
    double idnumber, balance;
}
```

The next part of the project is to create a `MyRecord` object array in my main method, which I do as stated:

```
 MyRecord recarray[] = new MyRecord[ARRAYSIZE];
 //ARRAYSIZE is 10
```

Next step is to scan and READ from a file which contains 5 records such as:

```
String filename = "data.txt";
File fileobject = new File(filename);
Scanner input = new Scanner(fileobject);
```

The program works perfectly fine up until this point, and it's reading from the file just fine but now here’s the problem: The project wants me to add those string records into the `MyRecord` array. I tried to do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    recarray[i] = input.next();      
}
```

But it throws out an error saying “Strings cannot be converted into `MyRecord` object array”. I kinda figured it would throw that error but I’m not sure how to solve this problem. So how would I convert the strings into the object and put them into the array? Or is there another way?

Also, this is what the records are, the file from where it's being read from:

```
Mary, Jane, maryj@gmail.com, 7654321, blue, 27.54
John, Doe, jd@yahoo.com, 123456, green, 19.24
Curly, Howard, nyuknyuk@msn.com, 888765, purple, 0.0
Bart, Simpson, donthaveacow@hotmail.com, 457673, magenta, 432.23
Clark, Kent, superdude@dailyplanet.com, 976834, red, 11.10
```

Sorry, I am fairly new to Java. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GBlodgett's answer is correct. I'll just add a code example of how you could collect the information from the file and put it into an array. For example:

```
String[] array = new String[6];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLinesToRead; i++) {
    recarray[i] = new MyRecord(); // Make sure to initialize the object before accessing it
    array = scan.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "").split(","); // The array object now contains each individual value of one line
    recarray[i].firstname = array[0];
    recarray[i].lastname = array[1];
    recarray[i].email = array[2];
    recarray[i].idnumber = Double.parseDouble(array[3]);
    recarray[i].color = array[4];
    recarray[i].balance = Double.parseDouble(array[5]);
}
```

This assumes that each data value for every line is read from the file in the same order (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, etc.).

Comment: maybe worth noting that it seems strange to me that the `id` is a double.  Either a `String` or an `int`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah, I thought the same thing. I guess that’s just what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are trying to resolve `input.next();` (A `String`) to `recarray[i]` which is an `MyRecord` object. You need to access the individual fields. So something like:

```
recarray[i].firstname = input.next();
```

And then when you get to the `double`'s you can do something like:

```
recarray[i].idnumber = Double.parseDouble(input.next());
```